# Windows 10: touchpad gesture with custom action (using config file programming)

Tags: windows, windows-10, gesture, touchpad, virtual-desktop

I have looked over the Internet for a way to change the actions of the different gesture on my touchpad on Windows 10 and did not find anything except the software made by the provider of the touchpad, which only allows me to reverse scrolling and enable/disable gestures.

Since Windows 10 introduced multiple virtual desktops, and that the 3 fingers swipe gesture only allows me to change windows in my actual virtual desktop, I wondered if anyone knew if there was something like TouchEgg on Ubuntu.

Here is an example of what TouchEgg allows you to do and how to do it : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43097/how-to-get-macbook-style-finger-gestures-on-ubuntu-linux/

Basically, there's a configuration file in which you can write a line of code to set an action for any gesture you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Windows Settings
- Search for "mouse", then access that window
- On the left bar you should find a tab called "TouchPad"; open that
- You will find settings there for your touchpad gestures

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: They asked specifically how to set the Windows gestures _programmatically_. This doesn't attempt to answer that question.